pillow: png при эффекте становится чёрным
img = Image.open('tiger2.png').resize((514, 470))


gradient = Image.new('L', (img.width, img.height), 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(gradient)
for y in range(img.height):
    draw.line([(0, y), (img.width, y)], fill=int(400 * (0.5 - y / img.height)))

img.putalpha(gradient.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(100)))

У меня есть такой код, который делает полупрозрачный градиент на фото. Все работает хорошо, но при использовании этого эффекта прозрачный png исчезает, и там где на оригинальном png фото прозрачный фон, после эффекта стает черный. Как можно пофиксить?

Ну наверное взять канал альфа из исходного изображения и как-то применить его к новому?

Вы используйте ключ L, который подразумевает отсутствие прозрачности, используйте ключ  RGBA

Так-же возможно нужно добавить альфаканал к исходному изображению img = img.convert('RGBA')
